# Call module function in event handler callback

Tags: c++

I wrote an Event System in C++, which is a bit useless at the moment, because all it can do is say that it handled and event. It can however emit and handle events with any payload type. The plan is to keep `Event` simple and just attach some kind of data to it (which can be as complex as required).

Then `EventHandler`s handles the event. Because `Event` is a template, `EventHandler`s must also be templated and cannot have its `HandleEvent` method be virtual. If it could, it would be the end of the story (you would just extend `EventHandler` and implement `HandleEvent` to use a ref of yourself).

So now I am stuck trying to figure out how to have `EventHandler::HandleEvent(Event<T> &event)` be able to call an object's method instead, to actually do something useful with the event. This is about my 8th rewrite of this system. So far every route I've gone to ends up with me not being able to handle the event however I want. I don't care if the method is ugly, I just want to make it easy to use.

*Note: stuck in c++ 98*

*Note: reading the EventEmitter code is not that important to understand the issue*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
```

> Event

```
template <class T>
class Event {
    public:
        Event(int id);
        int id;
        T payload;
};

template <class T>
Event<T>::Event(int id):id(id){}
```

> EventHandler

```
class EventHandler {
    public:
        EventHandler();
        template <class T>
        void HandleEvent(Event<T> &event);
};

EventHandler::EventHandler(){}

template <class T>
void EventHandler::HandleEvent(Event<T> &event){
    std::cout << "Handled event " << event.id << std::endl;
}
```

> EventSystem

```
class EventSystem {
    public: 
        void On(int id, EventHandler *handler);
        template <class T>
        void Emit(Event<T> &event);
        void GetEventHandlers(int id, std::vector<EventHandler*> *&handlers);
        std::map<int, std::vector<EventHandler*> > events;
};

void EventSystem::GetEventHandlers(int id, std::vector<EventHandler*> *&handlers){
    std::map<int, std::vector<EventHandler*> >::iterator it = this->events.find(id);
    if(it != this->events.end()){
        handlers = &it->second;
    }
    else {
        std::vector<EventHandler*> _handlers;
        this->events.insert(std::pair<int, std::vector<EventHandler*> >(id, _handlers));
        it = this->events.find(id);
        handlers = &it->second;
    }
}


// subscribe to an event
void EventSystem::On(int id, EventHandler *handler){
    std::vector<EventHandler*> *handlers = 0;
    this->GetEventHandlers(id, handlers);
    if(handlers){
        handlers->push_back(handler);   
    }
}

// emit an event
template <class T>
void EventSystem::Emit(Event<T> &event){
    std::map<int, std::vector<EventHandler*> >::iterator it = this->events.find(event.id);
    if(it != this->events.end()){
        for(size_t i = 0; i < it->second.size(); i++){
            it->second[i]->HandleEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

> Module

```
class Module {
    public:
        EventHandler event_handler;
        EventHandler alarm_handler;
        void OnEvent(Event<int> event);
        void OnEvent(Event<float> event);
        void OnEvent(Event<std::string> event);
};
// would love to call these somehow for each associated event
void Module::OnEvent(Event<int> event){

}
void Module::OnEvent(Event<float> event){

}
void Module::OnEvent(Event<std::string> event){

}
```

> main

```
int main(){    
    EventSystem es;
    Event<int> eventa(1);
    Event<float> eventb(2);    
    Event<std::string> alarm(3);

    Module module;

    es.On(1, &module.event_handler);
    es.On(2, &module.alarm_handler);
    es.On(3, &module.event_handler);

    es.Emit(eventa);
    es.Emit(eventb);
    es.Emit(alarm);    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EventHandlers must also be templated and cannot have its HandleEvent method be virtual.

Of course your event handler can be both templated and virtual.

Having built a more complex version of this sort of thing (an asynchronous event dispatcher that marshals events between objects and across threads), I recognize what you are trying to do.

The solution involves:

- Having a non-templated base class, `BaseEventHandler` for `EventHandler<T>` to derive from.
- Then the `EventSystem` class, for the most part references pointers to the base class instead of the derived `EventHandler` class.
- `dynamic_cast` to the rescue.

I cleaned up your code a bit and removed a few unnecessary template definitions in your code and then all your template classes or template functions are inlined. Despite all the things you've heard about not having code in header files,  templates are the exception.

Here you go:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

template <class T>
class Event {
public:
    Event(int idvalue) : id(idvalue)
    {
    }
    int id;
    T payload;
};    

class BaseEventHandler
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseEventHandler() {} ; // need at least 1 virtual method for dynamic cast
};

template <typename T>
class EventHandler : public BaseEventHandler {
public:
    virtual void HandleEvent(Event<T>& event) = 0;
};    

class EventSystem {
public:
    void On(int id, BaseEventHandler* handler);
    template <class T>
    void Emit(Event<T>& event)
    {
        std::map<int, std::vector<BaseEventHandler*> >::iterator it = this->events.find(event.id);
        if (it != this->events.end()) {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < it->second.size(); i++) {

                BaseEventHandler* pBaseEventHandler = it->second[i];
                EventHandler<T>* pHandler = dynamic_cast<EventHandler<T>*>(pBaseEventHandler);
                if (pHandler){
                    pHandler->HandleEvent(event);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void GetEventHandlers(int id, std::vector<BaseEventHandler*>*& handlers);
    std::map<int, std::vector<BaseEventHandler*> > events;
};

void EventSystem::GetEventHandlers(int id, std::vector<BaseEventHandler*>*& handlers) {
    std::map<int, std::vector<BaseEventHandler*> >::iterator it = this->events.find(id);
    if (it != this->events.end()) {
        handlers = &it->second;
    }
    else {
        std::vector<BaseEventHandler*> _handlers;
        this->events.insert(std::pair<int, std::vector<BaseEventHandler*> >(id, _handlers));
        it = this->events.find(id);
        handlers = &it->second;
    }
}    

// subscribe to an event
void EventSystem::On(int id, BaseEventHandler* handler) {
    std::vector<BaseEventHandler*>* handlers = 0;
    this->GetEventHandlers(id, handlers);
    if (handlers) {
        handlers->push_back(handler);
    }
}


class Module : public EventHandler<int>,
               public EventHandler<float>,
               public EventHandler<std::string>
{
public:
    void HandleEvent(Event<int>& event);
    void HandleEvent(Event<float>& event);
    void HandleEvent(Event<std::string>& event);

    void RegisterEvents(EventSystem& es);

};
// would love to call these somehow for each associated event
void Module::HandleEvent(Event<int>& event) {
    std::cout << "Integer event\n";
}
void Module::HandleEvent(Event<float>& event) {
    std::cout << "Float event\n";
}
void Module::HandleEvent(Event<std::string>& event) {
    std::cout << "String event\n";

}

void Module::RegisterEvents(EventSystem& es)
{
    es.On(1, (EventHandler<int>*)this);
    es.On(2, (EventHandler<float>*)this);
    es.On(3, (EventHandler<std::string>*)this);
}

int main() {
    EventSystem es;
    Event<int> eventa(1);
    Event<float> eventb(2);
    Event<std::string> alarm(3);

    Module module;
    module.RegisterEvents(es);


    es.Emit(eventa);
    es.Emit(eventb);
    es.Emit(alarm);
}
```

I started by having separate derived classes for each event type that called back into your module.  But you said you wanted the `OnEvent` methods in Module to be invoked.  So to keep it simple, I just replaced `OnEvent` with `HandleEvent` in your module class and let Module derived from all the different instances of `EventHandler`.  You could easily have a separate class implement HandleEvent and then invoke `module->OnEvent` as appropriate. Ala:

```
class AlarmEventHandler : public EventHandler<std::string> {
public:
    AlarmEventHandler(Module* module) : _module(module) {}
    HandleEvent(Event<std::string>& event) {
        _module->OnEvent(event);
    }
    Module* _module;
};
```

Now, a couple of design things I'd like you to think about as you evolve your code to production level.

- What happens when an event handler Emits another event (or the same event?)
- How do event handlers unsubscribe?  And what happens if an event handler unregisters itself (or another handler) in a callback.
- Consider having Emit taking the paylaod parameter and constructs the Event object on behalf of the caller.  That is `es.Emit(3, "something happened")` instead of requiring the caller to laboriously create an `Event<string>` thing himself.
- Bonus points if you can find a clever way to have Event take a collection of payloads instead of a single type.  (Use the dynamic cast and base class trick again).
- Consider passing events and event payloads to callbacks as const so one callback can't mess up what another caller receives.

Comment: Thanks, precisely what I was aiming for. I was stuck on not being able to inherit the template. I'm finding C++ has a lot more gotchas than I was prepared for, especially right as I approach the end of a module design! Nope! Can't do that!

Comment: @spin_round_22 - glad to have helped. You might also want to look at the [Boost Signals2 library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/signals2.html), [Qt Signals and Slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html),  and the [Event Aggregator pattern](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html)